# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate incompatibility

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, incompatibility

I have downloaded some sample projects of windows phone 8 and trying to open the project (.sln file) but it is showing me [image: this message].

so i Upgraded project but after this it is not supporting in VS 2013 Ultimate. Solution explorer is getting crashed and designer is showing error .
Project file (.csproj) have these two ProjectTypeGuids
**C089C8C0-30E0-4E22-80C0-CE093F111A43 , fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc**.

Designer is showing like these
[image]

When i trying to open .cs file visual studio getting crashed (i.e stopped working).

Comment: "getting crashed and designer is showing error" is not a problem description that is useful. What does "getting crashed and showing error" mean **specifically**? I can't see your screen from here, so I don't know what "getting crashed" means, and I certainly can't tell what "showing error" might mean. What exact steps can I take to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Which windows OS version are you using?

Comment: Have you downloadet the SDK, and running a windows 8 OS, and a I series intel process?

Comment: I am using windows 8.1 enterprise of x64 bit platform.